# CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE Broadcast Android O

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo

We have a wifi based application which has few millions of customer base. Core logic of the application is to connect the user to public open Hotspot with auto sign-in feature when connected. Application wholly depends on these broadcasts.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Following broadcast, app will check connected wifi hotspot and try auto login.

In Android O, app doesn't receive any of the above mentioned broadcast. Looked into background service with broadcast receiver workaround and seems like android is stopping the service some time.

Any suggestion is well appreciated.

Comment: Use a foreground service and `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the suggestion. This might effect user experience as foreground service remains in the notification window.

Comment: AFAIK, for your desired functionality, you have little choice in the matter.

Answer (score 4):

Use `JobScheduler` (`JobIntentService` or `Firebase Job Dispatcher` for backward compatibility). Refer the [latest video from Android Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc).

Using the method `JobInfo.Builder.setRequiredNetworkType()` you can schedule jobs to run when specific network conditions are met.

Quoting from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289411/4586742):

> The network type can be one of three values:
>
> - JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE: No network connectivity required.
> - JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED: An unmetered WiFi or Ethernet    connection.
> - JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY: Any network connection (WiFi or    cellular).

`JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED` would suit your needs.

Comment: I will give it a try and update you. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Isham hey. Was it work? I use badoo dating application on android 9 AOSP and when I turn on the wifi connection after 7 or 8 hourse waking up, it sends me notification.

Answer (score 2):

Just register to the broadcastReceiver at runtime instead of in manifest.

If you need to do it in a service that always runs, do it in a foreground service.

Read [**here**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt) or [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) for more information, as apps targeting Android 7.0 and above won't get this intent anymore via the manifest:

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive
>   this broadcast if they declare the broadcast receiver in their
>   manifest. Apps will still receive broadcasts if they register their
>   BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is
>   still valid.

I've made an easy way to register at runtime, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49774730/878126).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the docs:

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive
>   CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver
>   in their manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
>   broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with
>   Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.
>   [Monitor for Changes in Connectivity](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

---

As The Docs and CommonsWare (in the comments) mentioned use a foreground service and register your receiver there