# Starting WorkManager task from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, android-workmanager

I have a BroadcastReceiver here:

NotificationServiceReceiver:

```
public class NotificationServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(RestService.ACTION_PENDING_REMINDERS_UPDATED)) {
        //Reminders updated
        NotificationServer.startNotificationWorkRequest(context);
    }
}
```

A Notification Server:

```
public class NotificationServer extends IntentService {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "NotificationService";
public static final String ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION = "com.android.actions.SHOW_NOTIFICATION";
// this is a bypass used for unit testing - we don't want to trigger this service when the calendar updates during
// the intergration tests
public static boolean sIgnoreIntents = false;
private WorkManager mWorkManager;
private LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> mSavedWorkStatus;

public NotificationServer() {
    super(NotificationServer.class.getName());
    mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
}

/**
 * Handles all intents for the update services. Intents are available to display a particular notification, clear all
 * notifications, refresh the data backing the notification service and initializing our timer. The latter is safe to
 * call always, it will check the current state of on-device notifications and update its timers appropriately.
 *
 * @param intent - the intent to handle. One of ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION,
 * ACTION_REFRESH_DATA or ACTION_INIT_TIMER.
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    startNotificationWorkRequest(this);
}

public void startNotificationWorkRequest(Context context) {
    WorkContinuation continuation = mWorkManager
            .beginUniqueWork(IMAGE_MANIPULATION_WORK_NAME,
                    ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                    OneTimeWorkRequest.from(CleanupWorker.class));

}
```

}

I want to start a WorkManager task onReceive of the Broadcast Receiver. The problem is I can't do this statically as I need access to the current WorkManager object. The example code that Google provides here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/background/BlurActivity.java

Grabs the ViewModel like this: `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BlurViewModel.class);`

I can't do this obviously because my notification server class is not a view model. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Hi @Dylan this questions is out of topic. Is it possible to use Work Manager as Broad cast receiver. My workmanger need to trigger on every one hour (This i can do by default) . But additionally i have to trigger the same workmanager while the location gets turn on.. Is it possible without using broad cast receiver?

Comment: I'm unsure. Just beware that implicit broadcasts will no longer work after Oreo https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk#prenougat. So if your location turning on ACTION is not specific to your application and it's not whitelisted, it won't work.

Comment: Is there any way to make this things happen?

Comment: I'm just as confused about this whole thing as you are, there's not a lot of documentation out there right now

Comment: Thanks for  the Update @Dylan. If you got anything please let me know..

Comment: @Suresh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android/52330503#52330503 Look at these answers for how to replace implicit broadcasts on Android 8 with Workmanager

Comment: ".setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(UNMETERED).build  " Is this will execute if the Network Change(Like On/Off WiFi)?   I think it's precondition to execute my work manager at any network type. Like Downloading large file only if WiFi is ON..  Please correct me.

Comment: Yes. It seems Workmanager is enqueuing this task to be completed once the user once the user is on an unmetered internet connection. Refer to this for the difference between the Networktypes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217283/detect-network-state-change-using-jobschedulers-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your support. The    .setRequiredNetworkType(UNMETERED) in Constrain is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that sees this, you can use `WorkManager.getInstance()` to get the WorkManager object statically. There is only one instance of WorkManager, just make sure you initialize it like this on the start of your application: `WorkManager.initialize(this, new Configuration.Builder().build());`

[Android Custom Work Manager Config official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration)